# How to get table target cell inside tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I am trying to get variable-height table cells implemented and what I thought would be an elegant solution turned out into a recursion/stack overflow:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return [cell heightForObject:...]; // passing data object on indexPath
}
```

All table cell labels and other view properties are initialized at creation time (in a usual `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` way). Thus my idea was that I could move height specific computing out of table controller to my custom cell implementation like this. I could use the same cell in other table controllers without little if any code duplication. `heightForObject:` could look at it's subviews, what fonts they are using and build that height value from that. Heck, I could even change font sizes for certain cell labels and they should theoretically update their height properly.

So as mentioned already - I am hitting that stack overflow issue with this code. How would I go of getting that target cell for which `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is being called?

Comment: I just thought to myself that this might be a result of how UITableView manages it's cell. Like if you scroll deep down into a table it will release previous cell objects and when you scroll up again it will re-create them with `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. So it would mean it's possible that it is asking for cell height even tho that cell is currently not allocated/initialized yet (like if you are at the bottom in the table). I wish there was a way to read actual cell properties/configuration when computing height.

Comment: The problem is as you diagnose; essentially the table wants to be able to display cell 8000 without necessarily keeping cells 0–7999 in memory and to know how far it is down the list. It's not a poor API design, it's specifically required by the constraints. If you have, say, eight types of cell then you can load the NIBs once at init time, store the heights somewhere and then use whatever logic you use to determine cell type from index to grab the relevant value for tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get the selected cell?

Then write:

```
UITableViewCell *actCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
                                           [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
```